# currency python bot not saving in json

Tags: python, json, discord.py

So, I'm currently trying to code a discord bot, and I created a function

```
def _save():
with open("currency.json", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump("money", "json_file")
```

and, the bot would work, but everytime I turn off the bot, and turn it on, none of the information on the currency.json file wouldn't save and it will default to that nobody has an account

Answer (score -1):

Open the json file with `a`.

```
import json
with open("currency.json", "a") as json_file:
    json.dump("foo", json_file)
```

When you use `w`, the file will be overwritten meaning, the file will be cleared and new text will be written to the file. But if I did not want to overwrite the text, I could use `a` which acts like the append function.